# What materials are used in a Rolls-Royce RB211-524 Engine?

Tags: engine, aerospace-materials

I am trying to know what materials (Specifically metals) are used in making a Rolls-Royce RB211-524 Engine. I already found what is used in engines in general, but is it the same for all? And if so, what could be different in this specific engine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some variation. The RB211 was to be one of the first engines to use a fan stage made in carbon fiber (Hyfil), but that plan was changed in a late stadium and the fan stage was done in titanium instead.  Conways did use Hyfil, IIRC.
Otherwise it's mostly steel and aluminium, with some titanium. Copper for the wiring etc.